# How to change MUI Card content on hover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking to change a Card with only an image to a Card with content. Essentially on my portfolio, I'd like to display my project's logo and then while hovering over it, it should show the title/languages used/description. I currently have my code as:

```
              <Card sx={{ width: 1, height: 250 }}>
                <CardActionArea>
                  <CardMedia
                    sx={{ 
                      height: 250,
                      ':hover': {
                        // call a function here I believe?
                      },
                     }}
                    image={project.image}
                    title="green iguana"
                  />
                </CardActionArea>
              </Card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simran Singh has the right idea. However the sample code changes CSS properties of the *CardMedia* component, while the question asks how to change the content of the MUI Card itself. The sample below changes the content of the MUI Card. It can be seen in this [live demo](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-76041355). The demo [code repository](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekofeigen/muicard-rollover) is available. The main code for the component is below.

### app.jsx

```
...

import img from './../assets/images/purple.jpg';

const App = () => {

    const [ isHovered, setIsHovered ] = useState( false );
    const project = {
        image: img
    };

    function handleMouseOver() {
        setIsHovered( true );
    }

    function handleMouseOut() {
        setIsHovered( false );
    }

    return (
        <Card sx={{ width: '360px', height: '250px' }}>
            <CardActionArea
                onMouseOver={ handleMouseOver }
                onMouseOut={ handleMouseOut }
            >
                { isHovered
                    ?     <CardContent sx={ { minHeight: '220px' } } >
                            <CardHeader
                                action={
                                    <IconButton aria-label="settings">
                                    <MoreVertIcon />
                                    </IconButton>
                                }
                                title="My Title"
                                subheader="All the cool languages"
                            />
                            <Box ml={ 2 }>
                                <Typography variant="body1" color="text.primary">
                                    More information...
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography variant="body1" color="text.primary">
                                    Description of my cool projects!
                                </Typography>
                            </Box>
                            <CardActions>
                                <IconButton>
                                    { 'Click Me to Learn More!' }
                                    <TouchAppIcon size={ 'large' } />
                                </IconButton>
                            </CardActions>
                        </CardContent>
                    :   <CardMedia
                            sx={{
                                height: 250,
                                '&:hover': {
                                    '*': 'inherit' // Nope. Code does not go here.
                                },
                             }}
                            image={ project.image }
                            title="green iguana"
                        />
                }
            </CardActionArea>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default App;
```

## Update

### Hover effect for multiple Cards

The needed changes are within the lines of the code shown below.

```
export default function Projects() {
    const [isHoveredId, setIsHoveredId] = useState( '' );
    let projectList;

    function handleMouseOver( ID ) {
        return () => {
            setIsHoveredId( ID );
        }
    }

    function handleMouseOut() {
         setIsHoveredId( '' );
    }

    if (ScreenDetection() === false) {
        projectList = (
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6 pt-10">
                {projects.map((project) => (
                    <Card sx={{ width: 1, height: 250 }}>
                        <CardActionArea
                            onMouseOver={handleMouseOver( project.title )}
                            onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
                            href={project.link}
                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                            target="_blank"
                        >
                            {isHoveredId == project.title ? (
```

Comment: This works really well! Since I am using a map, every time I scroll over one of the cards, all of them get triggered. Is there a way to make it so that only the one I hover over gets changed?

Comment: @sandycheeks Could you please post your code? I can look to see how it could be updated. Thanks.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-resonance-5jvwkx?file=/src/App.js This is the code-sandbox link! Thank you!

Comment: @sandycheeks Does the `project` object have an ID or something that can uniquely identify it? So far, I only see **title** as a potential unique identifier.

Comment: It doesn't have an ID, but it would be extremely easy to add an ID tag as 1, 2, 3... onwards

Comment: @sandycheeks Updates are within the code shown in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can only trigger `CSS` using `sx` prop of **MUI**. To trigger functions you can wrap your `Card` components with a `div` and use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` properties.

Here is a very basic example of it:

```
  const [myColor, setMyColor] = useState('red');

  <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
     <div onMouseEnter={() => setMyColor('green')} onMouseLeave={() => setMyColor('red')}>
        <CardMedia sx={{ height: 140, border: '2px dashed', borderColor: myColor }}
        />
     </div>
  </Card>
```

I hope it helps.